# ContentChooser does not work in one app

Tags: android, basic4android

I am working on a slide show app. An earlier version using the ContentChooser in the phone library works perfectly.

This larger app fails to load the ContentChooser. The actual code to call it is the same in both apps, and is identical to the B4A examples.

This is the logcat result:

Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras) } from pid 11230
** Activity (createedit) Pause, UserClosed = false **
Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{408addc8 TS.SlidePro/.createedit}

'some memory freeing activity

Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!

So it seems to be a timeout issue. Any ideas what to do about it? The activity in question is rather complex. Is there any way to request extra time?

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

GS

Answer (score 0):

What happens afterwards?

You should check Sub Activity_Pause and make sure that you it is quick enough.

Comment: That is the answer. I had a piece of code in Activity paused which opened an inputdialog. The dialog never opened soI forgot it was there.

Comment: That was where the problem was. Thanks!